# Django: Resolve a related field to QuerySet type

Tags: python, django, types, pylint

Based on the official documentation:

```py
# Declare the ForeignKey with related_name
class Tag(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(
        Article,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="tags"
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

# Return all tags
Article.tags.all()
```

My linter (django-pylint) is unable to type it porperly: `Article.tags is Any`, I expected a `QuerySet[Tag]`.

---

Can I declare the `Article.tags` reference in the `Article` class? (preferred approach)

```py
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    # Related field declaration
    tags: QuerySet[Tag]

Article.tags.all()
```

Or maybe I need to convert it every time I need it?

```py
tags_qs: QuerySet[Tag] = Article.tags
tags_qs.all()
```

In both scenarios, it looks heavy to implement for each related field.

---

Of course, it's more a question for comfortable development experience than a critical issue.
The goal is to allow my linter and other autocompletion/discovery tools to resolve related fields as `QuerySet[T]` type. Maybe I can't due to the design of the Python implementation, more than a Django issue.

**Is there any other alternative to fix this problem?**

Comment: no idea if this helps your specific case, but try installing https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs library ...the Django codebase itself doesn't have type annotations

Comment: @Anentropic Amazing! I didn't know that we could improve Python typing, thanks for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Anentropic for pointing me in the right way, I opted for [django-types](https://github.com/sbdchd/django-types). This library can be easily integrated with VS Code and the PyLance extension (which uses PyRight type checking, not MyPY).

### Setup with VS Code

1. Clone [django-types](https://github.com/sbdchd/django-types)
2. Rename `django_stubs` to `django`
3. Move it into `./typings/django` in your project folder

### Adaptation

Following this instructions: https://github.com/sbdchd/django-types#usage

```py
from __future__ import annotations  # or just be in python 3.11

from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from django.db.models import Manager

class Article(models.Model):
    tags: Manager["Tag"]

# Declare the ForeignKey with related_name
class Tag(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(
        Article,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="tags"
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

# Return all tags
Article.tags.all()
```

Now, PyLance working fine with autocompletion!

Comment: If you are using a virtualenv then you don't need to clone django-stubs into your project, just install it into your virtualenv and make sure VS Code knows which virtualenv you have selected.  Another common pattern is to have two requirements files, a `requirements.txt` that is only the libs needed for deployment and a `requirements-dev.txt` with extra packages that are only needed for development (such as tools for running the test suite, mypy, django-stubs etc)